# How to write .CMD files from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

How does one write to a valid .CMD (or .BAT) file from PowerShell?  I'm using the `>` operator but `cmd.exe` can't execute the files I create.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.  [For comparison, I also write to a .CMD file from `CMD.EXE` and show that it works fine]

In PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> "@set BAR=1" > bar.cmd  // write to a .CMD file from PowerShell
```

In CMD.EXE:

```
C:\> echo @set FOO=1 > foo.cmd  // write to a .CMD file from CMD.EXE
C:\> type foo.cmd               // display .CMD file written from CMD.EXE
@set FOO=1                      // PASS
C:\> type bar.cmd               // display .CMD file written from PowerShell
@set BAR=1                      // PASS
C:\> call foo.cmd               // invoke .CMD file written from CMD.EXE
C:\> echo %FOO%
1                               // PASS
C:\> call bar.cmd               // invoke .CMD file written from PowerShell
C:\> ■@                         // FAIL
'■@' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I suspect that `bar.cmd` is being created with an encoding not support by `call` in `CMD.EXE`. [Although notice that `type` has no problem displaying the contents of `bar.cmd` in its current encoding.]

What's the proper way to programmatically write to a .CMD file from PowerShell such that it can be invoked from `CMD.EXE` with `call`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Set-Content bar.cmd '@set BAR=1' -Encoding ASCII
```

PowerShell will default to UTF-16 LE.

Short version.

```
sc bar.cmd '@set BAR=1' -en ASCII
```

Comment: Or you can use Out-File e.g.: `'@set BAR=1' | Out-File bar.cmd -enc ascii`

Comment: I stay away from Out-File as a general rule because it invokes the default console formatting (which means automatic line wrapping among other things).