# ANSI Encoding via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ansi

I have a PowerShell script that creates a batch file.
If I use the `Out-File` cmdlet without forcing any specific encoding, it will create a file that is perfectly readable to myself, but will not execute.

If I open this file in Notepad and resave it using "ANSI" format, it will execute fine.

I have tried using the `-Encoding` option with each of the different options associated with that switch, but none of them produce a batch file that is capable of being executed.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46426594/edit) your question and post your code !

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287245/how-to-write-cmd-files-from-powershell